Why does the web request use internet settings?
Hello I have an application, middleware application,
When I use C# HttpWebRequest it exhibits the same behavior as Internet explorer.
I cannot access a site with Internet Explorer that I can access with Chrome and Mozilla.
This being the case, no matter what method I use, I cannot get a correct response with HttpWebRequest
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true; // it does not work


ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications); // it does not work

private bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; }

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol // I tried them all one by one and it doesn't work.

I think I have tried all known methods ,I even made these settings via Internet Explorer, but it does not communicate at all. I tried another library, restsharp, and it didn't connect either.
The problem is that my customer opens Chrome and says I can access the site and there is no problem. However, I am trying various methods with C# but I cannot reach it. No restrictions on the server


Consider not support IE. Its no longer supported by Microsoft so why should you? This is old .Net Framework (<= 4.8) code right?

If IE does not open a site, I cannot access it either. Yes, my version is 4.7.2 which is lower than 4.8. But if I know the problem will be fixed, I will move on immediately, but it's not about this either. On another computer, the application runs smoothly with 4.7.2.
I haven't checked the version installed on this computer, but I don't know if it's up to date or should I check it?

Just to understand. You are talking about a client side application and you need to connect to somewhere but you can't. The talk about Browsers was just to show the behavior but your problem is just with HttpWebRequest that on old frameworks just surfaces OS functionality that depends on IE settings? Then you might want to find out what TLS versions are supported by the website you want to reach. If there is no intersection of the supported TLS versions of your presumably old client system you might be out of luck.

@Ralf  Yes, I am developing a client side application. The site I want to connect to supports TLS 1.2. Windows version Windows Server 2012 Datacenter

Another system out of support ;) When its a server OS i would try to talk to the admin in charge of that machine. Maybe he has hardened that machine because he knows of the risk having such a machine still on the internet and has disabled things relevant here for you.

@ralf  I said but The customer information processor is unaware of the issue. When the customer sees it opening in Chrome.  He says Chrome is connecting but your app isn't connecting. So how did Chrome open this?

Chrome/Firefox use their own Stack concerning SSL/TLS and the hole Certificate stuff connected to that. IE uses the Windows build in stuff and that's pretty outdated on Server 2012 and no longer supported. So you are comparing a out of support Net Framework, Windows Version, Internet Explorer to a presumably current Chrome that does the problematic stuff all by its own not relying on anything else.

This is exactly what I want to investigate.  Is it so difficult to do this? Can't I do it? Can't I download the certificate requested by the site and connect using this certificate from the application?

"Is it so difficult to do this" Yes. Its way more then having the cert. You can get that easily anyway (the public key).  And with everything security related don't simply do it yourself when you don't have the knowledge/experience and a chain of knowledgeable people behind you certifying that what you did is correct and safe. Updating to Net Core / updating the server is way more secure, easier and presumably even less costly then trying to implement security yourself.
